# Converting bytearray to short int in python

Tags: python, arrays, short

I have a long bytearray

```
barray=b'\x00\xfe\x4b\x00...
```

What would be the best way to convert it to a list of 2-byte integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) module:

```
import struct

count = len(barray)/2
integers = struct.unpack('H'*count, barray)
```

Depending on the endianness you may want to prepend a `<` or `>` for the unpacking format. And depending on signed/unsigned, it's `h`, or `H`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `struct` package for that:

```
from struct import unpack

tuple_of_shorts = unpack('h'*(len(barray)//2),barray)
```

This will produce *signed* shorts. For unsigned ones, use `'H'` instead:

```
tuple_of_shorts = unpack('H'*(len(barray)//2),barray)
```

This produces on a *little-endian* machine for your sample input:

```
>>> struct.unpack('h'*(len(barray)//2),barray)
(-512, 75)
>>> struct.unpack('H'*(len(barray)//2),barray)
(65024, 75)
```

In case you want to work with *big endian*, or little endian, you can put a `>` (big endian) or `<` (little endian) in the specifications. For instance:

```
# Big endian
tuple_of_shorts = unpack('>'+'H'*(len(barray)//2),barray)  # unsigned
tuple_of_shorts = unpack('>'+'h'*(len(barray)//2),barray)  # signed

# Little endian
tuple_of_shorts = unpack('<'+'H'*(len(barray)//2),barray)  # unsigned
tuple_of_shorts = unpack('<'+'h'*(len(barray)//2),barray)  # signed
```

Generating:

```
>>> unpack('>'+'H'*(len(barray)//2),barray)  # big endian, unsigned
(254, 19200)
>>> unpack('>'+'h'*(len(barray)//2),barray)  # big endian, signed
(254, 19200)
>>> unpack('<'+'H'*(len(barray)//2),barray)  # little endian, unsigned
(65024, 75)
>>> unpack('<'+'h'*(len(barray)//2),barray)  # little endian, signed
(-512, 75)
```

Answer (score 4):

Note, using the Python [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) library to convert your array also allows you to specify a repeat count for each item in the format specifier. So `4H` for example would be the same as using `HHHH`.

Using this approach avoids the need to create potentially massive format strings:

```
import struct

barray = b'\x00\xfe\x4b\x00\x4b\x00'
integers = struct.unpack('{}H'.format(len(barray)/2), barray)

print(integers)
```

Giving you:

```
(65024, 75, 75)
```

Answer (score 2):

If memory efficiency is a concern, you may consider using an `array.array`:

```
>>> barr = b'\x00\xfe\x4b\x00'
>>> import array
>>> short_array = array.array('h', barr)
>>> short_array
array('h', [-512, 75])
```

This is like a space-efficient primitive array, with an OO-wrapper, so it supports sequence-type methods you would have on a `list`, like `.append`, `.pop`, and slicing!

```
>>> short_array[:1]
array('h', [-512])
>>> short_array[::-1]
array('h', [75, -512])
```

Also, recovering your `bytes` object becomes trivial:

```
>>> short_array
array('h', [-512, 75])
>>> short_array.tobytes()
b'\x00\xfeK\x00'
```

Note, if you want the opposite endianness from the native byte-order, use the in-place `byteswap` method:

```
>>> short_array.byteswap()
>>> short_array
array('h', [254, 19200])
```